# How to breakline in Latex subsection?

Tags: latex

I have a subsection that goes like this `\subsection{blah blah blah \\ blah blah}`. The `\\` way of breakline doesn't work here. Can someone advise? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please make a [mre]. This will depend on what documentclass and packages you load. (anyway `\\ ` in not for line breaks, using it outsides tables is almost always wrong)

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Hi! I'm using the ```\documentclass[]{deedy-resume-openfont}``` and basically I'm trying have a subsection that contains the name of my university. However, I believe it exceeds the column margin hence I'm trying to break the line!

Comment: Please make a [mre], a small but compilable test document. It makes helping you much easier if we don't have to spend time trying to reproduce your problem first.